# How to get readonly textbox value in gridview c# from code behind

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a grid and I need to get readonly textbox value in gridview c# from code behind

Comment: can you post your code please

Comment: Sooo, what's the problem? If you know the exact coordinates (row, column), you can just use `datagridview.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].Value.ToString()` to retrieve the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void grd1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           if (txt.Text != "")
            {
                txt.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
                txt.Visible = false;
                lbltaskname.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                txt.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do itself on aspx page.

Assuming that dataset is attached(bind) to the grid from code behind, now coming to gridview on aspx page , add textbox control to grid , in text property of texbox assign value from dataset by -

```
<%# Bind("your_column_name")%>
```

and add

```
readonly = true
```

to textbox.

Thanks